# how to set timezone in soap request

Tags: java, soap, calendar, timezone

I need to add timezone to my soap request dateTime field.

See below snippet of my Java service client ,

```
Calendar cancelDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

I can see below timezone setting when i did debug :

```
zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/GMT-3"

java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1539843209365,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/GMT-3",offset=10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=42,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=291,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=13,SECOND=29,MILLISECOND=365,ZONE_OFFSET=10800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

But in soap request it pops like this (shows 3 hours before now):

```
<CancelDate>2018-10-18T06:10:07.738Z</CancelDate>
```

There is no timezone attached after time info. What I want is in request:

```
2018-10-18T16:23:20.000+03:00
```

So what should I do to achieve this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Correction: `Z` in the date-time in the SOAP request is an offset meaning UTC or offset 0 from UTC.

Comment: Do I need to set offset ?

Comment: Depends on what the server needs. If it just needs a point in time then `2018-10-18T13:23:20.000Z` and `2018-10-18T16:23:20.000+03:00` would be equivalent. If it uses the offset for something, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a `T` and a `Z` eg : `2021-05-16T00:00:00Z`

Answer (score 0):

I use this inline in soapUi:

```
"${= Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone('CET')).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")}"
```

Result:

```
"2021-03-09T11:09:02+0100"
```

Comment: maybe this better:`"${=new Date().plus(7).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",TimeZone.getTimeZone('CET'))}"`